# the accuracy of LDA predict for new documents with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lda

I'm work with Mllib of Spark, and now is doing something with LDA.

But when I use the code provided by Spark(see bellow) to predict a Doc used in training the model, the result(document-topics) of predict is at opposite poles with the result of trained document-topics.

I don't know what caused the result.

Asking for help, and here is my code below:

train:`$lda.run(corpus)` the corpus is an RDD like this: `$RDD[(Long, Vector)]` the Vector contains vocabulary, index of words, wordcounts.
predict:

```
    def predict(documents: RDD[(Long, Vector)], ldaModel: LDAModel):        Array[(Long, Vector)] = {
    var docTopicsWeight = new Array[(Long, Vector)](documents.collect().length)
    ldaModel match {
      case localModel: LocalLDAModel =>
        docTopicsWeight = localModel.topicDistributions(documents).collect()
      case distModel: DistributedLDAModel =>
        docTopicsWeight = distModel.toLocal.topicDistributions(documents).collect()
    }
    docTopicsWeight
  }
```

Comment: I assume you're seeing this problem when `ldaModel` is a `DistributedLDAModel`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your question actually concerns on why you were getting errors on your code but from I have understand, it seems first that you were using the default Vector class. Secondly, you can't use case class on the model directly. You'll need to use the `isInstanceOf` and `asInstanceOf` method for that.

```
def predict(documents: RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)], ldaModel: LDAModel): Array[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)] = {

    var docTopicsWeight = new Array[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)](documents.collect().length)
    if (ldaModel.isInstanceOf[LocalLDAModel]) {
      docTopicsWeight = ldaModel.asInstanceOf[LocalLDAModel].topicDistributions(documents).collect
    } else if (ldaModel.isInstanceOf[DistributedLDAModel]) {
      docTopicsWeight = ldaModel.asInstanceOf[DistributedLDAModel].toLocal.topicDistributions(documents).collect
    }
    docTopicsWeight

}
```

Comment: your code is just modified some format and it seems not effective for solving my question. Could you please add some explanation?

Comment: It's not just about formatting. Plus, you question actually isn't clear.

Comment: Thank's for your help. I'll try you code. And my question is not so clear because I'm the first time to ask question on stack overflow. When I use a doc in training(It has a doc-topics result. For example, a topic, 5th, have a weight of 0.8) as input of predicting, the predicted result has an almost balanced topic weight(maybe the 5th topic's weight is 0.1)

Comment: I'm sorry Carlos, I still don't understand the problem. Try to divide it into input ,ouput and expected output

Comment: Well, could you please tell me how did you do predict with LDA model on spark?

Comment: @Carlos, I think the way you're doing prediction is OK (except you don't really need the `var`, reassignment, etc. in there...) I suspect the discrepancies your seeing have something to do with issues in the variational inference of the `LocalLDAModel`. What happens if you call `predict` several times? Do you get (significantly) different topic weights for the documents each time? Do any of these look more reasonable?

Comment: Jason seems to have understood your issue so far. But the problems isn't in the var declaration.