# Spark LDA consumes too much memory

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, lda

I'm trying to use spark mllib lda to summarize my document corpus.

My problem setting is as bellow.

- about 100,000 documents
- about 400,000 unique words
- 100 cluster

I have 16 servers (each has 20 cores and 128GB memory).

When I execute LDA with `OnlineLDAOptimizer`, it gives out of memory error, suggesting me to increase `spark.driver.maxResultSize` like
**Total size of serialized results of 11 tasks (1302 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize**

I increased `spark.driver.maxResultSize` to 120GB (and also `spark.driver.memory` to 120GB) and re-run LDA but no lack.
It still says **Total size of serialized results of 11 tasks (120.1 GB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize**

I tried another dataset with about 100,000 unique words and it worked.

So, how can I estimate the memory usage when using Spark mllib LDA? I couldn't find any specification in the official documentation.

Note I used sparse　vector for constructing docuemnt `RDD[(Long, Vector)]` passed to `LDA.run()` but don't know whether spark lda can handle sparse format correctly in internal.

(editted) I used Scala version of LDA. Not Python version.

This may be a related issue but no clear answer was given.
[Spark LDA woes - prediction and OOM questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090222/spark-lda-woes-prediction-and-oom-questions)

(edited)

This is a snippet of my code (gist).
https://gist.github.com/lucidfrontier45/11420721c0078c5b7415

```scala
def startJob(args: RunArgs)(implicit sc: SparkContext): Unit = {
    val src = sc.textFile(args.fname, minPartitions = args.n_partitions).map(_.split("\t"))
        .flatMap {
            // input file's format is (user_id, product_name, count)
            case Array(u, p, r, t) => Some((u.toInt, p.toInt, r.toDouble))
            case _ => None
        }.persist()

    // Map to convert user_id or product_name into unique sequencential id
    val userid_map = src.map(_._1).distinct().zipWithIndex().collect().toMap
    val productid_map = src.map(_._2).distinct().zipWithIndex().collect().toMap
    val inverse_userid_map = userid_map.map(_.swap)

    // broadcat to speedup RDD map operation
    val b_userid_map = sc.broadcast(userid_map)
    val b_productid_map = sc.broadcast(productid_map)
    val b_inverse_userid_map = sc.broadcast(inverse_userid_map)

    // run map
    val transformed_src = src.map { case (u, p, r) =>
        (b_userid_map.value(u), b_productid_map.value(p).toInt, r)
    }

    println("unique items = %d".format(b_productid_map.value.size))

    // prepare for LDA input RDD[(LONG, Vector)]
    val documents = transformed_src.map { case (u, p, r) => (u, (p, r)) }
        .groupByKey()
        .map { t => (t._1, Vectors.sparse(b_productid_map.value.size, t._2.toSeq)) }.persist()

    documents.count()
    src.unpersist()

    // run Online Variational LDA
    val ldamodel = new LDA()
        .setK(args.k)
        .setMaxIterations(args.n_iter)
        .setOptimizer("online")
        .run(documents)
        .asInstanceOf[LocalLDAModel]


    val result = ldamodel.topicDistributions(documents)
        .map { case (i, v) =>
            val u = b_inverse_userid_map.value(i)
            "%d,%s".format(u, v.toArray.mkString(","))
        }
    result.saveAsTextFile(args.out)
}
```

Actually, I use LDA for dimensional reduction of transaction data. My data is in the format of `(u, p, r)`
where `u` is user id, `p` is product name, `r` is the number user `u` interacted with `p`. user corresponds to document and product to word in this case. Since user id and product name are arbitrary string, I converted them to unique sequential integers before submitting to LDA.

Thank you.

Comment: As a note, `mllib` LDA does handle sparse vector properly when training.

Comment: @Mai Yes, I thought that. Still don't know why I'm in short of memory.

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Comment: @zero323 I updated my post to include snippet of my code. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Thanks, it would be better to have this inside a question.. LDA returns at least two relatively large local objects `topicsMatrix` (#docs * #clusters) and `describeTopics` (this is proportional to (#clusters * #tokens * 2). At first glance it shouldn't account for 120GB but it still a lot.

Comment: @zero323 I know that LDA scales with O(#doc*#clusters + #words*#clusters) and should not consume that much memory. In fact, the case of #words = 100,000 was OK with 20GB memory, and I thought  80GB should be enough for #wores = 400,000.

Comment: This is still a lot for a single machine. How much memory did it consume with 100K words? Driver alone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106213/discussion-between-shiqiao-du-and-zero323).

Comment: This is an old question, but I'm still running into this problem (spark 1.6.1) - what I found is that setting the number of features for `HashingTF` in the spark pipeline to `2^18-1` (one less than the default) everything works fine and I can save the entire pipeline with `spark.driver.memory=1g`. Using the default `2^18` causes the save operation to produce a heap space OOM error. I also tried increasing the `spark.driver.memory` and `spark.driver.maxResultSize` to `8g` but that didn't help with `2^18` features - it's not clear to me if it's the driver of the workers that run out of memory.

Comment: What is your output path that you supply to `.saveAsTextFile( ... )`.

Answer (score 1):

There are three common causes for this problem, which may work independently or in tandem.

1. The job returns a lot of data to the driver using something like `collect`. Alas, some of the SparkML code does this. If you cannot blame (2) or (3) below for the problem, it's likely the outcome of how your data interacts with the `OnlineLDAOptimizer` implementation.
2. The job involves a large number of tasks, each of which returns results to the driver as part of Spark's job management (as opposed to with something like `collect`). Check the number of tasks in the SparkUI. Also see [Exceeding `spark.driver.maxResultSize` without bringing any data to the driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774845/exceeding-spark-driver-maxresultsize-without-bringing-any-data-to-the-driver) Are `org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager#canFetchMoreResults` or `org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter#enqueueSuccessfulTask` on the stack trace?
3. An estimation error: Spark significantly over-estimates the size of data that's about to be returned to the driver and throws this error in order to prevent a cluster's driver from OOM. See [What is spark.driver.maxResultSize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087859/what-is-spark-driver-maxresultsize) One way to test for this is to set `spark.driver.maxResultSize` to 0 (no limit) and see what happens.

Hope this helps!