Databricks spark stuck with 0 running while collecting delta table
I am executing this simple code on databricks:
df = spark.read.table(table_name).sample(fraction=0.1)
my_df = df.collect()

I'm accessing an external managed Delta Table on my Unity Catalog, the table has the following properties:
Size
3.1GiB, 13 files

Columns 
13

The cluster I am using is quite big, m4x10large with 160GB or memory, and im also heavily downsampling the data.
The code executes quite quickly, but then it gets stuck forever here:

And the cluster is doing absolutely nothing in the meanhwile. I looked at the logs, and the only thing that caught my attention is:
2024-09-20T11:10:57.351+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 36727934K->1398166K(35979264K)] 37066227K->1736467K(119453184K), 13.8056805 secs] [Times: user=68.37 sys=1.95, real=13.80 secs] 

That is spammed until eventually the clusters simply dies, I think because of some timeout set from databricks.
Any idea of where to start to debug this? The dataset has been optimized as at first I thought it could have been a problem with partitioning.

instead of my_df = df.collect(), can you try display(df)
to see the top 1000 rows

The display worked with no problems at all and was incredibly fast. Displaying the first 10000 rows didn't give any problems
The collect still gets stucked

Actually, replacing .collect() with .count() would be fist step to assess what kind of array you're trying to materialize on your driver.

This is the row count: 417146533. However, with polars (on the same machine) I am able to read the whole dataset in memory with no problems and also quite fast (only 30 seconds). Spark gets stuck for 15+ minutes doing nothing

I don't think there is much sense comparing two radically different technologies. Spark is a distributed compute engine. Its driver function is to plan, distribute, and manage parallel work of workers, rather than collect() humongous amounts of data onto itself.

What's the driver size? The collect method will bring all the data to the driver and if its close to the memory we are trying to fetch, it will result in garbage collection.
If display(df) is working without any problem, driver size could be the potential issue.

I am using a single node cluster on databricks. I configured the spark.driver.maxResultSize = 120g. However, it is interesting how I am able to read the whole dataset in memory without any problems or OOM with polars. But spark.collect() gets stuck forever doing nothing

check for spark.driver.memory... , spark.driver.maxResultSize is just a limit of total size of serialized results of all partitions for each Spark action (e.g. collect) in bytes. This limit  helps to protect the driver from out-of-memory errors. Having a high limit may cause out-of-memory errors in driver (depends on spark.driver.memory and memory overhead of objects in JVM). Source - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087859/what-is-spark-driver-maxresultsize
