# Does spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold work for joins using Dataset's join operator?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to know if `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` property can be useful for broadcasting smaller table on all worker nodes (while making the join) even when the join scheme is using the Dataset API join instead of using Spark SQL.

If my bigger table is 250 Gigs and Smaller is 20 Gigs, do I need to set this config: `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` = 21 Gigs (maybe) in order for sending the whole table / `Dataset` to all worker nodes?

**Examples**:

- **Dataset API join**

  ```scala
  val result = rawBigger.as("b").join(
    broadcast(smaller).as("s"),
    rawBigger(FieldNames.CAMPAIGN_ID) === smaller(FieldNames.CAMPAIGN_ID), 
    "left_outer"
  )
  ```
- **SQL**

  ```sql
  select * 
  from rawBigger_table b, smaller_table s
  where b.campign_id = s.campaign_id;
  ```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

First of all `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` and `broadcast` hint are separate mechanisms. Even if `autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` is disabled setting `broadcast` hint will take precedence. With default settings:

```scala
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold")
```

```
String = 10485760
```

```scala
val df1 = spark.range(100)
val df2 = spark.range(100)
```

Spark will use `autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` and automatically broadcast data:

```scala
df1.join(df2, Seq("id")).explain
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [id#0L]
+- *BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#3L], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=Some(8))
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
      +- *Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=Some(8))
```

When we disable auto broadcast Spark will use standard `SortMergeJoin`:

```scala
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
df1.join(df2, Seq("id")).explain
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [id#0L]
+- *SortMergeJoin [id#0L], [id#3L], Inner
   :- *Sort [id#0L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0L, 200)
   :     +- *Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=Some(8))
   +- *Sort [id#3L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- ReusedExchange [id#3L], Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0L, 200)
```

but can forced to use `BroadcastHashJoin` with `broadcast` hint:

```scala
df1.join(broadcast(df2), Seq("id")).explain
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [id#0L]
+- *BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#3L], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=Some(8))
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
      +- *Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=Some(8))
```

SQL has its own hints format (similar to the one used in Hive):

```scala
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

spark.sql(
 "SELECT  /*+ MAPJOIN(df2) */ * FROM df1 JOIN df2 ON df1.id = df2.id"
).explain
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
*BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#3L], Inner, BuildRight
:- *Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=8)
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
   +- *Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=8)
```

So to answer your question - `autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` is applicable when working with `Dataset` API, but it is not relevant when using explicit `broadcast` hints.

Furthermore broadcasting large objects is unlikely provide any performance boost, and in practice will often degrade performance and result in stability issue. Remember that broadcasted object has to be first fetch to driver, then send to each worker, and finally loaded into memory.

Answer (score 30):

Just to share more details (from the code) to the great answer from [@user6910411](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43984818/1305344).

---

Quoting the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L115) (formatting mine):

> **spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold** configures the maximum size in bytes for a table that will be broadcast to all worker nodes when performing a join.
>
> By setting this value to -1 broadcasting can be disabled.
>
> Note that currently statistics are only supported for Hive Metastore tables where the command `ANALYZE TABLE  COMPUTE STATISTICS noscan` has been run, and file-based data source tables where the statistics are computed directly on the files of data.

`spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` defaults to 10M (i.e. `10L * 1024 * 1024`) and Spark will check what join to use (see [JoinSelection](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala#L111) execution planning strategy).

There are **6** different join selections and among them is broadcasting (using `BroadcastHashJoinExec` or `BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec` physical operators).

`BroadcastHashJoinExec` will get chosen when there are joining keys and one of the following holds:

- Join is one of CROSS, INNER, LEFT ANTI, LEFT OUTER, LEFT SEMI and right join side can be broadcast, i.e. the size is less than `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`
- Join is one of CROSS, INNER and RIGHT OUTER and left join side can be broadcast, i.e. the size is less than `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`

`BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec` will get chosen when there are **no** joining keys and one of the above conditions of `BroadcastHashJoinExec` holds.

In other words, Spark will automatically select the right join, including `BroadcastHashJoinExec` based on `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` property (among other requirements) but also the join type.

Comment: Sure! Here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26214 happy to make Spark better

Comment: What do you mean by `no joining keys`? Does this mean not an `equi-join` or something?

Comment: `no joining keys` is when your query does not use `ON` in SQL or no keys in `Dataset.join` operator. Makes sense? Keep asking until you're fine with the answer. I might eventually look at the sources again to make sure I've got this all right :)

Answer (score 1):

there is limitation that maximum size of DF that can be broadcast is 8G.
And you can split the dataframe and then based on your lkp logic to LKP the sub-dataframe in iterative way.