# Can I set different autoBroadcastJoinThreshold value in sparkConf for different sql？

Tags: apache-spark, broadcast, skew

I have large DataFrames：**A(200g), B(20m), C(15m), D(10m), E(12m)**, I want to join them together: **A join B**, **C join D and E** using spark sql in same SparkSession**. Just like:

```
absql:sql("select * from A a inner join B b on a.id=b.id").write.csv("/path/for/ab")
cdesql:sql("select * from C c inner join D d on c.id=d.id inner join E e on c.id=e.id").write.csv("/path/for/cde")
```

**Problem:**

When I use default `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=10m`

- absql will take long time, the reason is absql skew.
- cdesql is normal

When I set `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=20m`

- C,D,E will be broadcasted and all of the tasks will be executed in same executor, it still take long time.
- if set num-executors=200, it take a long time to broadcast
- absql is normal

Comment: @Shaido 's answer can solve my problem. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984068/does-spark-sql-autobroadcastjointhreshold-work-for-joins-using-datasets-join-op) let me know function `broadcast` is not affected by the parameter `autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing `autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`, you can mark the dataframes to be broadcasted. In this way, it's easy to decide which dataframes should be broadcasted or not.

In Scala it can look like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
val B2 = broadcast(B)
B2.createOrReplaceTempView("B")
```

Here dataframe B has been marked for broadcasting and then been registered as a table to be used with Spark SQL.

---

Alternatively, this can be done directly with the dataframe API, the first join can be written as:

```
A.join(broadcast(B), Seq("id"), "inner")
```

Comment: Thank you @Shaido! It's is very helpful to me. In this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984068/does-spark-sql-autobroadcastjointhreshold-work-for-joins-using-datasets-join-op)