# Broadcasting multiple view in SQL in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, broadcast

I want to use BROADCAST hint on multiple small tables while joining with a large table. In the example below SMALLTABLE2 is joined multiple times with the LARGETABLE on different joining columns. Now to get the better performance I want both SMALLTABLE1 and SMALLTABLE2 to be BROADCASTED. Can this be achieved by simply adding the hint /* BROADCAST (B,C,D,E) */ or there is a better solution? SMALLTABLE1 & SMALLTABLE2 I am getting the data by querying HIVE tables in a Dataframe and then using createOrReplaceTempView to create a view as SMALLTABLE1 & SMALLTABLE2; which is later used in the query like below.

Is there anyway BROADCASTING view created using createOrReplaceTempView function?

```
SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, B.COL4, C.COL5, D.COL6, E.COL7
FROM LARGETABLE A
JOIN SMALLTABLE1 B
ON A.LCOL = B.SCOL
JOIN SMALLTABLE2 C
ON A.LCOL1 = C.SCOL
JOIN SMALLTABLE2 D
ON A.LCOL2 = D.SCOL
JOIN SMALLTABLE2 E
ON A.LCOL3 = E.SCOL
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spark 2.2+ then you can use any of these `MAPJOIN/BROADCAST/BROADCASTJOIN` hints.

Refer to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16475) Jira and [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/14132)  for more details regarding this functionality.

> **Example:** below i have used **broadcast** but you can use either **mapjoin/broadcastjoin** hints will result same explain plan.

```
>>> spark.range(1000000000).createOrReplaceTempView("t")
>>> spark.range(1000000000).createOrReplaceTempView("u")
>>>sql("select /*+ Broadcast(t,u) */* from t join u on t.id=u.id").explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#16L], Inner, BuildRight
:- *Range (0, 1000000000, step=1, splits=56)
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
   +- *Range (0, 1000000000, step=1, splits=56)
```

(or)

if you are using Spark < 2 then we need to use dataframe API to persist then registering as temp table we can achieve in memory join.

```
>>> df=hc.range(10000000)
>>> df.persist() --persist the df in memory
>>> df.registerTempTable("u") --register temp table
>>> df1=hc.range(10000000)
>>> df1.persist()
>>> df1.registerTempTable("t")
>>> hc.sql("select * from t join u on t.id=u.id").explain()
== Physical Plan ==
Project [id#11L,id#26L]
+- SortMergeJoin [id#11L], [id#26L]
   :- Sort [id#11L ASC], false, 0
   :  +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(id#11L,200), None
   :     +- InMemoryColumnarTableScan [id#11L], InMemoryRelation [id#11L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(false, true, false, false, 1), ConvertToUnsafe, None
   +- Sort [id#26L ASC], false, 0
      +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(id#26L,200), None
         +- InMemoryColumnarTableScan [id#26L], InMemoryRelation [id#26L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(false, true, false, false, 1), ConvertToUnsafe, None
```

> ***By using DataFrames without creating any temp tables***

```
>>>from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df=hc.range(10000000)
>>> df1=hc.range(10000000)
>>> df.join(broadcast(df1),['id']).explain()
== Physical Plan ==
Project [id#26L]
+- BroadcastHashJoin [id#26L], [id#11L], BuildRight
   :- ConvertToUnsafe
   :  +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#26L]
   +- ConvertToUnsafe
      +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#11L]
```

in addition Broadcast joins are done automatically in Spark.

There is a parameter is "**spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold**" which is set to **10mb by default**.

To change the default value then

```
conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", 1024*1024*<mb_value>)
```

for more info refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984068/does-spark-sql-autobroadcastjointhreshold-work-for-joins-using-datasets-join-op) link regards to **spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold**.